# IE conditional comment not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements, stylesheet, comments

I'm having a bit of a problem with the conditional comment for IE.

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
       type = "text/css"
       href = "css/stil.css" />

 <!--[if IE]>
  <link rel = "stylesheet"
        type = "text/css"
        href = "css/ie.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

It's not working in IE9, IE9 loads the normal stylesheet (css/stil.css) and not the one i specify in the conditional comment. Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IE9 loads the normal stylesheet (css/stil.css) and not the one i specify in the conditional comment.

From that sentence, it sounds like you're not expecting IE to download and apply the `css/stil.css` stylesheet. It should and will. It's just that it should *also* download and apply the `css/ie.css` stylesheet. Could it be that you're seeing styles from `css/stil.css` that you aren't expecting? On the face of it, [the conditional comments work fine](http://jsbin.com/ucacay) (I had to use `style` rather than `link` elements in that example, but the concept is the same).

Comment: Ok problem solved i forgot that i had to make IE ignore the other stylesheet so here is the solution

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
       type = "text/css"
       href = "css/stil.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->